# is there a better way for Dumping dictionary into a json

Tags: json, python-3.x

I used dump function from import json to convert dictionary to json.
It took me 16 seconds to convert around 550K items in the dictiorary.
Is there any faster way than this ?

Comment: I'd assume the bottleneck here is the time to write that much data to a file, check how long `json.dumps` takes, if it's much less then the issue is the IO not json.

Comment: @Tadhg McDonald-Jensen , I ran the program again. There is no difference, the whole program took 15.58 seconds and the json.dumps 15.56 seconds.

Answer (score 1):

You could try doing the encoding yourself:

```
d = {0:'1',1:'2'}

result = '{'
for k,v in d.items():
    result += '"{}":"{}",'.format(str(k),str(v))
result = result[:-1] + '}'
```

Which *might* be faster, but you could lose some additional functionality that `dumps` requires. Some cursory testing suggests my method is way slower, but you could probably fine tune it if need be.

Additionally, there are other 3rd party JSON libraries. [Here](http://artem.krylysov.com/blog/2015/09/29/benchmark-python-json-libraries/) is a performance comparison which suggests [rapidjson](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-rapidjson) might work for you better.